# How is pandas.json.dumps implemented?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've been scouring the internet for hours now and I'm stumped. Pandas has a method `dumps`(accessible via `pandas.json.dumps`) that can encode any arbitrary object to a json string. The builtin `json.dumps` would normally just throw an exception.

I've been looking at source code trying to find the implementation of this function but I can't find it. Does anyone have the implementation or have an idea of how this would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search through the Pandas GitHub repository shows that `pandas.json.dumps` appears to be implemented by the [`objToJson`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/78fcce40c4e19f8e3a1b32d103c56c52124c284a/pandas/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c#L2509) function defined in [`pandas/src/ujson/python/objToJson.c`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/78fcce40c4e19f8e3a1b32d103c56c52124c284a/pandas/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c).